# Serializable class as parameter in function call?

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin. I get a type mismatch in function call "encodeString". What would be the right interface for the definition of the method?

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
class TypeA(val a: Int)
class TypeB(val a: Int)

class Test {
    fun encodeString(obj: Serializable): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(obj)
    }

    fun doSomethingWithA() {
        val a = TypeA(5)
        encodeString(a)
    }

    fun doSomethingWithB() {
        val b = TypeB(5)
        encodeString(b)
    }
}
```